# how to show 2 partial views on the same page

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I just started using **asp.net mvc** and I have a question. In my current project which is the login forms and registration forms that microsoft give as example, I have a **log in page** and **a register page** that  share the **same Layout.** I want to show both log in page and register page on the same page. I created a partial view for log in page and for register page as well. I want to keep the same layout but with register and log in forms as well.

How should I continue?

Shall I include the partial view pages to the layout?

I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Create one view. Suppose the name is login.cshtml.
Now create one partial view _registration.cshtml . Now render the partial view in login.cshtml.
Note- login will use the layout